# How to get instagram user data (ex follow count) through facebook.com api with http request

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I want to get instagram user data for example follow and follows count using http request to [https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{inst_acc_id}](https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/%7Binst_acc_id%7D) but i cant understand which token from graph api explorer i should use. There is lots of types and lots of permissions there. i tried different ones and all of them doesn't work for me. Or maybe there is another easier way to get instagram user data after the 2020 api change.
I need a solution for my NodeJs project, but it would be great to make it work even in plain http in postman. Any advices are highly apreciated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after the 2020 update you don't have an easy way to get even public data from meta ( facebook and insta). To get access for their api you need to provide a lot of personal data about your business, your website and a lot of other documents for them to review your request. And if you are trying to have a simple website that shows for example your instagram followers count its a giant overkill. And no other way around.